# How to autodoc private instance attributes in sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I usually initialize all instance attributes in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
"""
Initializer docstring.
"""
    self.test1 = None  #: test1 docstring
    self._test2 = None  #: test2 docstring
    self.test3 = None
    """test3 docstring"""
    self._test4 = None
    """test4 docstring"""
```

I would like to have all my instance attributes documented, including the private ones.

To generate the documentation I used the following code:

```
.. automodule:: module_name
    :members:
    :member-order: bysource
    :show-inheritance:
    :private-members:
    :special-members:
```

Yet private instance attributes are still omitted. What do I miss?

I use python 2.7, Sphinx 1.2.3, and sphinx-rtd-theme 0.1.9.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some additional tests and I still was not able to generate documentation for private attributes. I do not have time to run through *autodoc* code to verify whether the problem is on my side or it is just a designer's choice. I came up with the following work around though (in case somebody else runs in the similar problem):

1. I document all the public attributes in the class docstring (as suggested by *NumPy* style).
2. I document all the private attributes in the `__init__` docstring (as I do initialize them all in there) using the notation for variables:

   ```
   :ivar _private_attribute: description.
   :vartype _private_attribute: int
   ```

As a result private attributes are documented in the *Variables* section. It is not perfect but it works for me.